# Can you access Thread State in .net Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Is it possible to get Thread state info in compact framework 3.5 ?

```
Thread th=new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoIT));
th.Start();

Thred.sleep(1000);
th.??? // is thread running, suspended, etc.?

void DoIT(){
  //do stuff in here and exit after some second
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Officially not supported according to [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/a043d754-1497-4dd1-8409-94bef9be10e1).

[Suggested Workaround](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/35120.aspx): use `Join(0)` and check return flag. **True** - terminated, **False** - still running

Comment: The second link has been eaten by the a grue :(

Comment: Is it not the other way around. True terminated, False stil running?

Comment: Although this is an old question, I did get a ThreadStateException upon Joining a thread if the thread has not started. Nice of Microsoft to generate a paradoxical ThreadStateException if ThreadState is not supported in CF.